# It is possible to port unity?

Tags: unity, unity-2d

I've been a Ubuntu user for long, but, because of the lack of software updates (Eclips since in 3.5, and others), and because Ubuntu (in my point of view) is becoming more and more resources hungry (for my little netbook :S), I've switched (before 11.04 was released) into Arch Linux and I'm very very happy with it.

But, since 11.04 is out, and I've tested Unity I have to say that I love it so much ! Before that I was addicted to Gnome 3 Shell (gnome-shell), but with the time I learned a little bit more about unity, and now I simply cannot leave without that ^^ (nice job for all the team btw !)

So I have a few questions (one related to my post little and another 2) :

1 - Because of the ubuntu dependencies, It is possibile to port Unity to a Gnome3 based installation ? (I have the time and (if I'm not wrong) the knowledge to do the most part of the porting. But I don't really know how to start since I never make a portage of an Huge project as this one :S...)

2 - Some ideas to improve unity that I can't make my self :S..
    2.1 - The name of the distro (Ubuntu) appears on the top, so the users know that when they are in the desktop then can access into a hidden menu (it can make it more beautiful too).
    2.2 - Like in OsX, the menu in the bar always visible (it's better I think).

So anyone can help me with that ? Porting and changing this settings on my existing Ubuntu 11.04 ?

PS : I'm not asking for anyone to work with me, just to tell me if it is possible a post for Gnome3 and guide me to the right sources and if possible an example of a working shell to appear in the GDM selection :S

Thanks in Advance for all your help,
And Sorry for my very bad english :S !

Comment: Can you make this either separate questions or one concrete question?

Comment: I'd personally say this is too big a task for one person. You need to hack compiz to work with gnome3 and then hack unity on top of that. This should be more feasible after 11.10.

Comment: I've asked since Gnome3 Fallback use a modified Gnome2, making compiz running perfectly on it and all the gtk2 app (that I've tested, but I've not tested to compile and run the actual unity :S)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity is already being ported to opensuse ;)

The next unity version is also gonna be using gtk3, so yes it's posible

Comment: Yeeahh ^^ ... euh I mean... ok thank you for the information ^^ I don't know if I can wait until october but thats nice... PS : did you have some link to the opensuse port ? Thanks in advance

Comment: mmm was searching again and  discover opensuse gived up >.<

Comment: argh ! Thanks anyway ^^... If i don't find a good way to port I will probably work on my own shell this can be a good idea for a personal use ^^ (just and idea)... thanks for all ^^